# Android InApp Billing v3 - testing with multiple devices issue

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm facing one issue on Android InApp billing v3. I have created a managed inapp product in playstore and I need to buy that multiple times from multiple devices. For that, I am testing the app in two different devices. I'm not keeping any purchase data on local server. So whenever I need to purchase that item again I'll query the item to get the purchase status and based on that if the item is purchased I'll consume the item and will call the purchase function again. I'm detailing my error scenario below

1. On the **first devices**, I have done with the payment and I got the success result.
2. On that same device if I query for purchase detail, it will give the exact info.
3. On the same time if I query on the **second device**. its gives the  `inventory.hasPurchase(sku)` as **false** and  `inventory.getPurchase(sku)` as **null**.

While googling, I found that this is something related to Google playstore cache and all. After doing that, cache clearing manually, I getting the result as expected. Could anybody guide me on the above mentioned issue.

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                invokePurchaseError(ResponseCode.FAILED_TO_QUERY_INVENTORY, result.toString());

            }
            else{

                if(mActionCode == RC_REQUEST_FOR_QUERYING){
                    boolean mIsPurchased = false;
                    Log.e("hasPurchase",  inventory.hasPurchase(mSku)+"");
                    Log.e("getPurchase",  inventory.getPurchase(mSku)+"");

                    if( inventory.hasPurchase(mSku)){
                        mPurchaseStatus = inventory.getPurchase(mSku);
                        mIsPurchased = (mPurchaseStatus != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(mPurchaseStatus));
                        if(mPurchaseStatus!=null){
                            mPurchaseStatus.getOriginalJson());
                        }
                        else{
                            //Not purchased
                        }

                    }

                }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Bought managed item on first device but second and third ones didn't seem to "know" about it. For me the solution was simple although:
As a first step I cleared the PlayStore-caches on all involved devices (not sure it is was necessary though..)
Secondly I bought the item again on the first device, but again the other ones seemed to fail getting the information. I gave the whole "system" some time (about 10-15minutes) and performed a re-check on device 2 and 3. And - oh wonder! - they finally got the correct `hasPurchase = true` information.